# How can we combine two compound inequalities?

Tags: inequality

I know how to add or subtract two inequalities. But I cannot find in anywhere how to add or subtract two compound inequalities. This problem is one of the example :

If $0 < x \leq 2$, and $y \geq 2$, determine $y-x$ and $x+y$.

This is my first time using stack exchange and I don't know how to use MathJax formatting. I appreciate your help so much.

Comment: Addition is preserved under the same inequalities: if $x < a$, $y < b$, then $x + y < a + b$ and if $x > a$ and $y > b$, then $x + y > a + b$. Also use that if $x > a$, then $-x < -a$. Do you think you can solve it knowing this?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding inequalities is fairly straightforward, so you can reason through a problem like this is this way: We have $0<x\le 2$, and we have $2\le y<\infty$. Therefore, $0+2<x+y<2+\infty$, which simplifies to: $2<x+y<\infty$.

To work with $y-x$, think of it as $y+(-x)$. We can find the inequalities for $-x$ by multiplying the inequalities for $x$ by $-1$: $-2\le -x<0$. This time, when we add, the left sides of both compound inequalities have $\le$ instead of $<$, so their sum does, as well: $2+(-2)\le y-x <0+\infty$.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I don't know why I didn't think of it like that before.

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with intervals:
$$\begin{align}0 < x \leq 2 \Rightarrow &x\in (0,2]\\
y\ge 2 \Rightarrow &y\in [2,+\infty)\end{align}$$
For $x+y$, you add the left (min) and right (max) borders (preserving the stricter inequality sign if any):
$$\quad \quad \quad \quad x+y\in (2,+\infty)$$
You can multiply an interval by constants (if negative, the interval is reversed):
$$\begin{align}x\in (0,2] \Rightarrow -x&\in [-2,0)\\
y&\in [2,+\infty)\end{align}$$
For $y-x=y+(-x)=-x+y$, you again add the left (min) and right (max) borders (preserving the stricter inequality sign if any):
$$-x+y=y-x\in [0,+\infty).$$
Exercise: Can you find $x-y$ ?